# Angular 6 Animation is not working in IE

Tags: angular

I have the following animation in Angular 6.

```
slide-in-out-animation.ts

    // import the required animation functions from the angular animations module
import { trigger, state, animate, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';

export const slideInOutAnimation =
  // trigger name for attaching this animation to an element using the [@triggerName] syntax
  trigger('slideInOutAnimation', [

    // end state styles for route container (host)
    state('*', style({
      // the view covers the whole screen with a semi tranparent background
      position: 'fixed',
      zIndex: 6,
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
    })),

    // route 'enter' transition
    transition(':enter', [

      // styles at start of transition
      style({
        // start with the content positioned off the right of the screen, 
        // -400% is required instead of -100% because the negative position adds to the width of the element
        right: '-400%',
        zIndex: 6,

        // start with background opacity set to 0 (invisible)
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
      }),

      // animation and styles at end of transition
      animate('.5s ease-in-out', style({
        // transition the right position to 0 which slides the content into view
        right: 0,
        zIndex: 6,

        // transition the background opacity to 0.8 to fade it in
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
      }))
    ]),

    // route 'leave' transition
    transition(':leave', [
      // animation and styles at end of transition
      animate('.5s ease-in-out', style({
        zIndex:6,
        // transition the right position to -400% which slides the content out of view
        right: '-400%',

        // transition the background opacity to 0 to fade it out
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
      }))
    ])
  ]);
```

When I want to use the animation in a Component:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-example-edit',
      templateUrl: './example-edit.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./example-edit.component.css'],

      // make slide in/out animation available to this component
      animations: [slideInOutAnimation],

      // attach the slide in/out animation to the host (root) element of this component
      host: { '[@slideInOutAnimation]': '' }
    })
export class ExampleComponent {

}
```

In parent-component.html
I have the html

```
<a href="#" routerLink="add">Add</a>
<div class="view-side-form">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In the parentcomponent I have a link to add a element. When the user click in the link. The content of examplecomponent is loaded using the animation. 
In chrome is working perfect. But in Internet Explorer the animation is not working. Also, the animation is working perfect using Angular5 in Chrome and IE.
The problem is when i want to use it with Angular 6.

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "app-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^6.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.15.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-datetime": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

polyfills.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

I am using the Animation created from the link [Angular 2/5 - Router Animation Tutorial & Example](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/04/19/angular-2-4-router-animation-tutorial-example). In Angular5 is working perfect in all browser, but when I want to migrate to Angular6 i have problems with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 6 animations require you to enable polyfills for IE and Edge, there's [a section in the Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills) related to these settings, here's the gist of it:

1. Uncomment the following line in your polyfills.ts in your projects root:

   > import 'web-animations-js';
2. Install the web-animations npm package:

   > npm install web-animations-js

Comment: Hi I have uncommented the line in polyfills but not working yet. I edited my Question.. I added the new package web-animations-js and the content of the file polyfills.ts. You can see that I have the line uncommented

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid I'll have to ask you to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for example on stackblitz.com

Comment: Hi, you can review https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grryts
In Chrome is working good, but in IE you can see the problem 
thanks

Comment: Curious, I can reproduce the bug via crossbrowsertesting but can't really debug, I'll check tomorrow when I've got access to a Win machine.

Comment: i'd want to migrate to Angular 6 but this problem is stopping me. thanks so much

Comment: I've tried to investigate the error ... I really can't come up with a good reason for why it's not working as intended. You may want to file a bug at the Angular repository.

Comment: I have opened a Bug in Angular repository [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24923) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24923) has been resolved via a [Pull Request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28911) and will be incorporated in yet to be determined future version of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

So, in IE Edge, I have figured out if you use the `keyframes` function it works. If you replace your `slideInOutAnimation` constant in **slide-in-out-animation.ts** with this. [Demo (edited from Pablo's example)](https://angular-fjnwum.stackblitz.io)

```
export const slideInOutAnimation =
  trigger('slideInOutAnimation', [
    state('*', style({
      position: 'fixed',
      zIndex: 6,
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
    })),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        right: '-400%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
      }),
      animate('.5s ease-in-out', keyframes([
        style({
          right: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
        })
      ]))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('.5s ease-in-out', keyframes([
        style({
          right: '-400%',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
        })
      ]))
    ])
  ]);
```